# como crear un boton para cambio de tema obscuro y claro en blogger

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy elaborando un blog pero no se como crear el código para activar y desactivar el modo obscuro y claro de la pagina y también una vez creado el código saber en que parte de la estructura de el código fuente debo insertarlo.

Comment: Ya probaste alguna de [estas opciones](https://www.google.com/search?q=blogger+plugin+for+dark+mode)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comento que dentro de la estructura lo puedes ubicar en la parte superior derecha de tu blog con algún diseño de Sol y Luna tipo icono, esto lo puedes conseguir en las diferentes librerías como por ejemplo [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=sun&o=r) y lo puedes asociar al hacer click a un cambio dinámico en JavaScript a través de escuchar dicho evento, tambien te agregue la función de alojar una cookie para que respete la decisión del usuario cuando vuelva a visitar la página, en el ejemplo la cookie expira en 7 días.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cambio de Modo</title>
<style>
body {
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modo-oscuro {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #434343 0%, black 100%);
    color: white;
}

.modo-claro {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #eeeeee, #dddddd, #cccccc, #bbbbbb);
    color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="modo-toggle">Cambiar Modo</a>
    <div class="modo-claro" id="contenido">
    <h2>Esto es una prueba</h2>
    <h3>Cambio de claro a oscuro</h3>
    <h3>presiona el boton</h3>
  </div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const modoToggle = document.getElementById("modo-toggle");
    const contenido = document.getElementById("contenido");

    // Recupera el estado almacenado en la cookie al cargar la página
    const modoActual = obtenerCookie("modo");

    // Aplica el modo actual al cargar la página
    if (modoActual === "oscuro") {
        activarModoOscuro();
    } else {
        activarModoClaro();
    }

    modoToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (contenido.classList.contains("modo-claro")) {
            activarModoOscuro();
            establecerCookie("modo", "oscuro", 7);  
        } else {
            activarModoClaro();
            establecerCookie("modo", "claro", 7);
        }
    });

    function activarModoOscuro() {
        contenido.classList.remove("modo-claro");
        contenido.classList.add("modo-oscuro");
    }

    function activarModoClaro() {
        contenido.classList.remove("modo-oscuro");
        contenido.classList.add("modo-claro");
    }

    function establecerCookie(nombre, valor, dias) {
        const fechaExpiracion = new Date();
        fechaExpiracion.setTime(fechaExpiracion.getTime() + (dias * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        const expira = "expires=" + fechaExpiracion.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = nombre + "=" + valor + ";" + expira + ";path=/";
    }

    function obtenerCookie(nombre) {
        const nombreC = nombre + "=";
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            let cookie = cookies[i];
            while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
                cookie = cookie.substring(1);
            }
            if (cookie.indexOf(nombreC) === 0) {
                return cookie.substring(nombreC.length, cookie.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te agradezco muchisimo que te tomaras la molestia de ayudarme , eres muy amable la verdad apenas vi la respuesta voy a intentar en este momento y nuevamente muchas pero muchas gracias dios te bendiga . si me lo permites recoemndare tu pagina para que te sigan mis contactos .

Comment: Gracias! Aqui estamos para ayudarnos todos entre todos...

Comment: Recuerda que si la respuesta es correcta debes marcarla para ayudar a todos los demas